# Get distance from user's location to nearest point on GMSPath

Tags: ios, google-maps, core-location, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am working with the Google Maps API and have drawn `GMSPolyline`s on the map. I know which "node" (lat and long position for a turning point) on the map is closest to the user's location, and I know the next upcoming nodes. Given that information, how could one obtain the distance from the user's current location to the nearest point on the closest path? In the diagram below, how could we get x when we know the three GPS coordinates?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this as a geometry problem instead of a programming problem might make this a little easier. There probably exists a library or API that does this with little more than a couple lines of code, but this approach should still yield a result with little to no overhead.
Disclaimer: This approach only works with straight lines.

You have two points that are on your path and one point that is not on the path. Using some [basic algebra](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/strtlneq3.htm) you can find a line that is parallel to the path and runs through the user's location, and then invert that line to find the shortest line between the user's location and the path. Then it's simply finding the intersection of two lines.

One thing to note, the larger the distance between nodes then the less accurate the euclidean distance will be. This should be negligible for nodes closer than ~100 miles.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this (swift 4.0)

```
func isApproaching(_ to:CLLocation, from:CLLocation? = nil, byDistanceInMeters:Double) -> Bool {

    guard let baseLocation = from ?? ThisIsMyDefaultUserLocationVariable.location else { return false }

    let delta = to.distance(from: baseLocation) as Double
    if delta < byDistanceInMeters { return true }
    return false
}
```

and this is how to call it:

```
if isApproaching(lastLocation, byDistanceInMeters: 50.0) ) {
    // this is where you are in 50m perimeter
} else {
    // here you are outside 
}
```

.

Comment: you may also find this one is helpfull (from GMS Documentation):
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/group___geometry_utils.html#ga580ba381b9d4fbc0ff430cf69e06e66d